# Expression Engine module DevDemon – Updater displaying php errors on local when run by MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, expressionengine, mamp-pro

In my local environment I have tried to install the Expression Engine module Updater by DevDemon. Both the master MAMP php.ini file and the local php.ini file have the following settings:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING display_errors = Off
```

However these errors are still displaying:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::arrayExtend() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: updater/api.updater.php

Line Number: 109
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::getThirdPartyPath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: updater/api.updater.php

Line Number: 132
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::getThemePath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: updater/api.updater.php

Line Number: 133
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Non-static method Updater_helper::getThirdPartyThemePath() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Filename: updater/api.updater.php

Line Number: 134
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Michael/Sites/creativevisuals/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 412
```

Why are these errors still displaying? I have tried restarting the MAMP server every time I have edited the `php.ini` files and `phpinfo()` reflects the fact that these settings are active.

When I run `phpinfo()` after Line 109 in `api.updater.php` the settings change however. Somehow this script is overriding the php settings. Why and where is it doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using PHP 5.6 which causes these errors. Most developers don't support it yet, if you want to get rid of the errors add a "static" in front of the function names.